# What's the meaning of "as much as we thirst for approval, we dread condemnation"

Tags: meaning

I'm reading Dale Carnegie's *How to Win Friends and Influence People*.

There is a quote that says, "As much as we thirst for approval, we dread condemnation."

What's the meaning of this?

**EDIT:**

The author of the book was trying to elaborate that criticism is a bad idea.

How is this sentence related to `criticism`?

Comment: A little elaboration – about what exactly is confusing you – would not be a bad thing.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Timeless. What exactly is confusing you about this quote? Have you looked up the words you don't know in a dictionary? What did it say?

Comment: Rewrite the sentence: "We dread condemnation as much as we thirst for approval."

Comment: Was the word "thirst" confusing you, or the "As much as ..." construction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*As much as we thirst for approval, we dread condemnation* means that we are afraid that other people might disapprove of us as much as we want them to approve of us.

In this context, *thirst* means to want something very badly, not that we need something to drink. *Dread* is great fear, and *condemnation* is strong disapproval.

Answer (score 3):

Carnegie is citing a [quote](http://www.searchquotes.com/quotation/As_much_as_we_thirst_for_approval_we_dread_condemnation./218763/) from [Hans Selye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Selye), but I'm inclined to think it doesn't have the exact sense of most statements using this well-established general format, which are normally along the lines of...

> *"As much as I love you, I can't leave my husband"*
>    *"As much as we want to, we just can't get married"*
>    etc., etc.

...where *As much as X, Y* essentially means *"**Even though** X is true/desirable, it is incompatible with Y*. It's normally used in contexts with the strong additional implicit meaning ***Y is the overriding factor***.

Selye was a Hungarian endocrinologist, much concerned with [biological stress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_%28biological%29) (which had not previously been significantly studied, or even recognised). Taking into account that background information, and Carnegie's likely intention in quoting the words, I think OP's quote is probably best interpreted literally, as simply saying our fear of condemnation and our desire for approval are ***equally*** strong conflicting urges.

That's to say, in this particular case, *as much as* probably really does mean *to the same extent that*, but normally it's a "set format" construction where the second "statement of fact" overrides the first "desire".

---

Noting OP's amendment that the quote was given in a context where Carnegie's main point was that *"criticism is a bad idea"*, and the fact that it's in a book supposed to teach you *how to win friends and influence people*, I imagine he's advising against [constructive criticism](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=constructive+criticism&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=7l4uUabzMeq30QXpy4GgDQ&ved=0CC8QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42965579,d.d2k&fp=2d067e3b3a7f4d22&biw=1421&bih=739). That's popularly interpreted as being where you explain what people are doing *wrong* (so they can change, and thus improve). But you make more friends by ignoring what they're doing wrong, and *praising what they do right*.

Answer (score 0):

As easy I could say, the hunger to achieve something is the same as fear of failing to achieve that thing.

Answer (score 0):

We seek so much for approval to look good in the eyes of somebody else as much as we fear to be criticized or ridiculed by someone, not appreciated

Comment: Hello Miglioli. Welcome to ELL. I have made a slight change in your post which you can view by clicking on the edit history right above my name. I hope you don't mind. If you feel it is wrong, feel free to rollback the changes.

Answer (score 0):

As much as we thirst for approval, we dread condemnation means that We have a fear that Other people will Disapprove our Idea/Thoughts.

In this context, thirst means to want something very badly, not that we need something to drink. Dread is great fear, and condemnation is strong disapproval.